# How to connect vb.Net application to Oracle using LDAP server?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, ldap, oid

For database connectivity to our Vb.net application we were using `Tnsnames.ora` .

But for now, We have the end files in a common LDAP server. We call it OID. We are stuck how to connect Oracle DB to our vb.net application using LDAP server.

Could you please provide any help regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your names are provided from LDAP server then you don't need `tnsnames.ora` file anymore.

In order to use LDAP server you have to change attribute `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH` in your `sqlnet.ora` file like this:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (LDAP, TNSNAMES)
```

This will first search in LDAP and - if nothing found - then search `tnsnames.ora` file.

Then you have to create a file called `ldap.ora` in the same directory with content similar to this:

```
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT = "dc=domain,dc=net"
DIRECTORY_SERVERS = (ldap-server1.domain.net:389:636,ldap-server2.domain.net:389:636)
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE = OID
```

Check documentation for details:

[Directory Usage Parameters (ldap.ora)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/ldap.htm#NETRF011)

[Parameters for the sqlnet.ora File](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF006)

Comment: Perfect @Wernfried Thanks a lot.